# In the OpenRTB bid requests, is "bundle" unique to an app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, mopub, double-click-advertising

I am looking at multple openRTB specs, for example from MoPub. They have a bundle field in their bid request. Bundle is a number 123456 for an iOS app, or package name for an android app like package.bundle.apname. 
Is this "bundle" unique to an app?

1. Can a single app have multiple "bundle"?
2. Can a single "bundle" might mean multiple apps?

Answer (score 4):

Great questions! Please see answers inline.

***Is this "bundle" unique to an app?***

--> Yes, "bundle ID" is a unique identifier for a single app within that platform's "app store ecosystem" (ecosystem = Android:Google Play Store, iOS:Apple app store)

For example, the "bundle ID" (aka 'Android Package name') for the [Android NYTimes app on the Google play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nytimes.android&hl=en) is 'com.nytimes.android' (listed in the URL). No other apps on the Google play store is permitted to use the bundle ID 'com.nytimes.android'. It is specific to the NYTimes Android app only.

On the iOS side, the "bundle ID" for the [iOS NYTimes app on the Apple app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nytimes-breaking-national/id284862083?mt=8) is 'id284862083' (listed in the URL). No other apps in the Apple app store is permitted to use the bundle ID 'id284862083'. It is specific to the NYTimes iOS app only.

***Can a single app have multiple "bundle"?***

--> No, a single app will have a 1-to-1 relationship with "bundle"

***Can a single "bundle" might mean multiple apps?***

--> No, I think you may be interpreting the term "bundle" literally. "Bundle" is also known as an "Android package" (this is set when you are developing your app). It uniquely identifies a **single app**. See this [great answer on Bundle ID for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705874/bundle-id-in-android).

**Was I able to answer your questions? Please don't hesitate to followup with any additional questions!**

Comment: Hi Kendrick, was I able to answer your question? If not, please let me know what was unclear so I can further clarify. if yes, would you mind clicking the "accept answer" button? Thanks!!

Comment: >Can a single app have multiple "bundle"?
>--> No, a single app will have a 1-to-1 relationship with "bundle"

Doesn't that answer assume the same app store? My understanding is that best practice is using different bundle names for different android app stores.